# How can I check to see if the user won?

Tags: c#, simulation

How to check to see if user won with a conditional?

```
                int score1 = 0;
                int score2 = 0;
                int score3 = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
                { //open for
                    if (score1 > score2 && score1 > score3) //open if
                        Console.WriteLine(name1 + " takes the lead in lap " + i + "!");
                    else if (score2 > score1 && score2 > score3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(name2 + " takes the lead in lap " + i + "!");
                    }
                    else if (score3 > score2 && score3 > score1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(name3 + " takes the lead in lap " + i + "!");
                    } //close if
                } // close for
            } //close if
```

This is the piece of code I am referring to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to solve the problem, you need 3 variables to which we add the various scores at each lap, this variables are then compared before the end of the while loop. The code posted shows only the comparison for the first option. I'm sure you can figure out how to compare for the remaining options.

```
   class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    { //open main method
        string name1 = "Buck";
        int endurance1 = 6;
        int speed1 = 4;
        string name2 = "Daisy";
        int endurance2 = 4;
        int speed2 = 6;
        string name3 = "Leo";
        int endurance3 = 7;
        int speed3 = 3;
        int balance = 100;
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the racetrack!\nToday's races will include 10 laps for reach race. There will be 3 races today. \nYou have $100 you can choose to bet on one of our 3 horses.\n1. Bet on a horse. \n2. Quit the game.");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        while (input == "1")
        { //open while1
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to bet on: \n1." + name1 + ": \nEndurance:" + endurance1 + "\nSpeed:" + speed1 + "\n2." + name2 + ": \nEndurance:" + endurance2 + "\nSpeed:" + speed2 + "\n3." + name3 + ":\nEndurance:" + endurance3 + "\nSpeed:" + speed3 + "\nPlease enter the name of the horse as it appears on the screen.");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();
            if (choice == "Buck")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have chosen " + name1 + ".");
            }
            else if (choice == "Daisy")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have chosen " + name2 + ".");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have chosen " + name3 + ".");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to bet? Your current balance is $" + balance + ".");
            string money = Console.ReadLine();
            int bet = int.Parse(money);
            Console.WriteLine("You are betting $" + bet + " on " + choice + ". Type \'start\' to start the race.");
            string race = Console.ReadLine();
            int totalScore1 = 0;
            int totalScore2 = 0;
            int totalScore3 = 0;

            if (race == "start")
            { // open if
                Console.WriteLine("Let the races begin!");
                for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
                { //open for
                    System.Random r = new System.Random();
                    int score1 = speed1 + endurance1 + r.Next(1, 8);
                    int score2 = speed2 + endurance2 + r.Next(1, 8);
                    int score3 = speed3 + endurance3 + r.Next(1, 8);
                    totalScore1 += score1;
                    totalScore2 += score2;
                    totalScore3 += score3;
                    if (score1 > score2 && score1 > score3) //open if
                        Console.WriteLine(name1 + " takes the lead in lap " + i + "!");
                    else if (score2 > score1 && score2 > score3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(name2 + " takes the lead in lap " + i + "!");
                    }
                    else if (score3 > score2 && score3 > score1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(name3 + " takes the lead in lap " + i + "!");
                    } //close if
                } // close for
            } //close if 
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Okay, take your time.");
            if(totalScore1> totalScore2 && totalScore1 > totalScore3 && choice =="Buck")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Buckl won the race");
            }
        } //close while
        Console.WriteLine("Aw, too bad. Thanks for joining us!");
    } //close main method
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solving your exact issue, I'd like to show you the power of collections (arrays and `Dictionary`). They allow you not to manually type every single condition for a single horse (imagine if you had 15 horses)

Since you're a novice, you probably will have hard time understanding this code, but watch and learn!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

struct Horse 
{
    public string name;
    public int endurance;
    public int speed;
};
    
class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var horseByName = new Dictionary<string, Horse> 
        {
            {"Buck", new Horse{ name = "Buck", endurance = 6, speed = 4 } },
            {"Daisy", new Horse{ name = "Daisy", endurance = 6, speed = 4 } },
            {"Leo", new Horse{ name = "Leo", endurance = 7, speed = 3 } },
            {"Maya", new Horse{ name = "Maya", endurance = 5, speed = 4 } },
            {"Richard", new Horse{ name = "Richard", endurance = 5, speed = 4 } },
        };
        int balance = 100;
        int numberOfHorses = horseByName.Count;
        
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the racetrack!");
        Console.WriteLine("Today's races will include 10 laps for reach race. There will be 3 races today.");
        Console.WriteLine("You have $100 you can choose to bet on one of our 3 horses.");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Bet on a horse.");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Quit the game.");
        
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        while (input == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to bet on:");
            int horseNumber = 1;
            foreach (var horse in horseByName.Values) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{horseNumber}. {horse.name}\nEndurance: {horse.endurance}\nSpeed: {horse.speed}");
                ++horseNumber;
            }

            string choice = Console.ReadLine();
            while (!horseByName.ContainsKey(choice)) 
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("We don't have such horse, try again:");
                 choice = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"You have chosen {choice}.");
            
            Console.WriteLine($"How much would you like to bet? Your current balance is ${balance}.");
            int bet = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine($"You are betting ${bet} on {choice}. Type \'start\' to start the race.");
            string race = Console.ReadLine();
            if (race == "start")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Let the races begin!");
                int[] scores = new int[numberOfHorses];
                int maxScorePerLap = 0;
                string maxScoredHorseName = "";
                
                for (int lap = 1; lap < 11; lap++)
                {
                    System.Random r = new System.Random();
                    int horseId = 0;

                    foreach (var horse in horseByName.Values) 
                    {
                        scores[horseId] = horse.speed + horse.endurance + r.Next(1, 8);
                        if (scores[horseId] > maxScorePerLap)
                        {
                            maxScorePerLap = scores[horseId];
                            maxScoredHorseName = horse.name;
                        }
                        ++horseId;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine($"{maxScoredHorseName} takes the lead in lap {lap}!");
                }
                if (maxScoredHorseName == choice) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Hurray! {choice} won!");
                    balance += bet;
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Unfortunately {maxScoredHorseName} won, but you had bet on {choice}...");
                    balance -= bet;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Okay, take your time.");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Aw, too bad. Thanks for joining us!");
    }
}
```